# Debugar variavel na camada model cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, debug

Como faço para dar um debug ou printf em uma variável no model para que ela seja exibida na tela? só consigo debugar as variáveis na view e no controller

```
 public function atualizaCatalogo(){    
        $arr_produtos_out = $this->conecta_produtos_atualizacao('ConsultaMercadoriasAIE', 'TipAtlMov', 'E');
        //debug($arr_produtos_out); tentei assim mas nao apresenta nada
        $arr_produtos_in = $this->conecta_produtos_atualizacao('ConsultaMercadoriasAIE', 'TipAtlMov' ,  'I');   
    $arr_produtos_altera = $this->conecta_produtos_atualizacao('ConsultaMercadoriasAIE', 'TipAtlMov' ,'A');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente dar um `var_dump($variavel)`, caso dentro do `Model` ou no `Controller` passar a variável para a `view`, após a chamada do `método`:

```
$this->set('result', $this->Model->atualizaCatalogo());
```

No cake também há a classe [`Debugger`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#CakeLog::write), que você pode utilizar.

$foo = array(1,2,3);

```
Debugger::dump($foo);

// outputs
array(
    1,
    2,
    3
)
```

Ou mesmo o [`CakeLog`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#CakeLog::write):

```
CakeLog::write('debug', 'Mensagem de log');
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certinho aqui!

Comment: O cake tem a função debug pra isso. ```debug($var);```